# Session instead of viewsate

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have found many questions here about storing values in viewstate, but haven't found a good answer.

I have a situation when i retrieve large amount of data from database. Then i filter and manipulate the data according to my needs (so it is a preety heavy process). Then I put the result inside a list of custom class. For example lets say this class will be Person

```
List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

private void FillPersons()
{
   //Call to webservice
   persons = ws.GetPersonsList();

   //Do all kind of custom filtering

   //Manipulate the data

}
```

Now the whole `FillPersons()` method is a heavy process that returns pretty small amount of data. And unfortunately it can't be moved to SQL and the heaviness is in the process, but that is not the point.

The point is that i need to reuse this data on the page between post backs. 
Right now in order to spare the additional call to `FillPersons()`  I mark Person class as serializeable and store the list in the viewstate, that works fine except the fact that the page becomes 1mb size because of the viewstate. According to what i have read, it is not so acceptable approach i.e. it is not secure and it blows the source code making the page heavy etc. (second is what most concerns me)

So it leaves me with a session. However session is persisted not only between postbacks, but much after it, even when user leaves the page. Or worst- the session will end before user decide to postback. So finding the best time span for session lifetime is mission impossible.

My question is what is the best practice to reuse "datasets" between postbacks?
What you guys do in such cases?

Thanks.

PS: hidden fields etc. is not an option.

Comment: Is this Person list application wide or filtered on the currently logged in user?

Comment: Can you persist it somewhere else after you first retrieve it, the filtered dataset? If so, you could store it along with a unique key and send only the key to the client.

Comment: What about a temp database table that stored cache data?

Comment: @Magnus it is filtered on the currently logged user and is much depends on user's data

Comment: I don't understand why there is no `ws.GetPersonsList(string filter, string sort)` overload in your webservice.

Comment: @GemCer but then ill have to run some scheduled job couple of times to dispose the data?

Comment: @Holystream but then ill have to run some scheduled job couple of times to dispose the data?

Comment: @TimSchmelter it doesn't really meter if i have or not as it makes no difference where the data is processed, in the ws or in the method. The process is just heavy and takes time to execute, so the key here is reuse

Comment: @jekcom: What i meant is, such things should be done by the dbms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store this kind of data in the [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx). It is application wide, so depending on what you add use the key accordingly.

```
var key = UserID + "_personList";
Cache.Add(key, personList, null, 
  DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60), 
  Cache.NoSlidingExpiration,
  CacheItemPriority.High, 
  null);
```

Note that you can never assume that the data is in the cache (it might have been flushed) so always check if it returns null and than refill it.

Comment: I agree.  If doing all of the filtering in the database (which is what it's there for) isn't permissible then caching the data is going to be the best option.  ViewState and Session shouldn't be abused with that.

Comment: `Cache` would have the advantage to not be persisted inside a hiddenfield ("__VIEWSTATE"), rather on the server ...

Comment: So what is the advantage of cache over the session?

Comment: It is application wide, you can set priorities, you can use sliding and fixed expiration.

Comment: Another advantage is that the data is ONLY pulled when you want it.  Whereas with session the data is serialized/deserialized on every page load.  In short, you have a LOT more control.

Comment: @Magnus ok. Thanks. One more question if you can answer. How would you implement this if the data would not be user depended. i.e. user retrieves the data once, then he performs all kind of postbacks? So the idiea is not having a UserID but also not letting this data to be shared between 2 different clients?

Comment: @ChrisLively the session is be default stored in process, it would only need serialized/deserialized on every page if it is stored in a stateserver such as SQL server. (if I remember correctly)

Comment: @jekcom you could use `Session.SessionID` as part of the key than.

Comment: @Magnus: Very true.  However in process suffers from the possibility of app pool recycling...  Which would result in loss of the Session ID and all associated data

Answer (score 2):

Viewstate is not a good way of storing large objects. As you mentioned your page size will get bigger and every postback will take lots of time.

I would suggest using cache. By using cache your list wont be saved there till end of session and you can set how much time it should be stored there. For caching you may use HttpCache or some distibuted caching system like [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849) or [MemCached](http://memcached.org/) . [This](https://nuget.org/packages/Glav.CacheAdapter) nuget package will help using these cache systems.

[this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingConfiguringAndUsingWindowsServerAppFabricAndTheVelocityMemoryCacheIn10Minutes.aspx) link will help how to configure AppFabric.

**I should edit with some code to make it more helpful.**

https://bitbucket.org/glav/cacheadapter/wiki/Home

```
var cacheProvider = AppServices.Cache; // will pick cachadapter using web.config ( can be Http, Memory, AppFabric or MemCached)

var data1 = cacheProvider.Get<SomeData>("cache-key", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(3), () =>
{
    // This is the anonymous function which gets called if the data is not in the cache.
    // This method is executed and whatever is returned, is added to the cache with the
    // passed in expiry time.
    Console.WriteLine("... => Adding data to the cache... 1st call");
    var someData = new SomeData() { SomeText = "cache example1", SomeNumber = 1 };
    return someData;
});
```

Comment: Interesting I'll look at this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Other than a cache (good idea by Magnus), the only other way I can think of is to keep the results of your heavy operation stored in the database server.

You mention that it takes a lot of time to retrieve the data.  Once done, store it in a purposely established table with some type of access key.  Give that key to the browser and use it for pulling what pieces you need back out.

Of course, without knowing the full architecture it's really hard to give a solution.  So, in order of preference:

1. Store it back in the database with a unique key for this user.
2. Store it in a remote cache
3. Store it in a local cache

Under no circumstance would I store it in the page (viewstate), cookie (sounds too big anyway), or in session.

Comment: "Store it back in the database with a unique key for this user."  the data may frequently change. The effective life time of the data is pretty much the time user stays on the page. And I think this way we lose flexibility, unless we serialize the list and store the object as is. But then would it hit the performance of the server to deserialize it each time we need it?

Comment: @jekcom: If you can't pull fresh data each time it's needed, then you are always going to deal with stale information regardless of where you put it.  The question really boils down to how out of date is acceptable.  If none, then you absolutely must pull it again.  If a few minutes (the time they would be on a page) then cache it.  Under no circumstance do you use session.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [ASP.NET caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hbbsfk6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?
You should choose a key that will suite your exact needs and you will have your data stored in the server memory. But keep in mind cache is application specific and is valid for all users.
If the data you process is not often changed, the processing algorithm doesn't depend on user specific settings and it is not critical to always have the latest data maybe this is the best option I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

Store your filtered collection on disk in a file. Give the file the same name as a key you can store in viewstate. Use that key to retrieve the file on postbacks. In order to keep the file system from filling up, have two folders. Alternate the days for which folder you save the files to. That way you can wipe out the contents of the folder that is not being used that day. This method has extremely good performance, and can scale with a web farm if your folder locations are identified by a network path.

Answer (score 0):

I think personlist is a shared object. Does everyone use the same list? You can store on Application.

```
 Application["PersonList"] =persons;

 persons = (List<"Person">)Application["PersonList"]
```

Or you can Store on Static class.

```
public static class PersonList   {   public static List<"Person"> Get {get;set;}  }
```

You should write this code to Application_Start on Global.asax file

```
PersonList.Get = ws.GetPersonsList();
```

And you can get List by using this code

```
persons = PersonList.Get;
```